# Travis basic understanding and set up

Tags: travis-ci

I have a little-to-none understanding of what [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) is. All I know ( and I could be wrong ) is that, it is where a github code is hosted. This code has a test written in Unit Tests, and Travis is a way to automatically test whenever a new commit is pushed to github. As I said, I could be totally wrong. Wikipedia article didn't help me understand this.

But, in the case that it is a test automation software, then how do I set up a simple application? I have a github account, and I know the first step is to register in travis, connect a github account and place a `travis.yml` file but what is next?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Correct. What you are talking about is just one of scenarios, but you have got that idea right. Here's an article that you might want to have a look: [Setup a Selenium WebDriver Ruby project on Travis CI](http://yizeng.me/2013/06/15/setup-a-selenium-webdriver-ruby-project-on-travis-ci/). That article is about Selenium WebDriver Ruby binding. Without knowing what your "test automation software" is, we could hardly provide any more detailed answers. Feel free to read through [Travis CI Documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Travis CI does is connects to your GitHub repository to run you code's tests (Scripts that write to confirm that your code is working) on every commit you make on GitHub. It also runs on pull requests, which makes it great for checking if a pull request breaks anything. You can get started by going to the [Travis CI](HTTPS://travis-ci.org) and hitting sign in on the top right corner. You'll sign in with your GitHub account, and on the profile page you can turn on the repositories that you want Travis CI to test. Next, you'll need to create a `.travis.yml` in the repositories you want to test. You didn't specify what language you to would like to use so I'll refer you to the [Travis CI getting started page](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/getting-started/) which has examples in every language that Travis CI supports.

If you want to read up more I reccomend taking a look at the [Travis CI docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com).